# Cannot iterate over the object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Struggling to iterate over the object in javascript. I can usually do the obvious key iteration and even tried some functions I have found for that purpose itself. Although, when I print the object to the console it works. I am struggling to access its properties. Puzzled. Lost quite some time with this so turning to stackoverflow for some help.

Assume I have a sitemap.xml stored somewhere locally.

```
<script>

    (function() {

        tree = new TreeModel();

        root = tree.parse({ name: "domain.com" });

        var rootNode = root.first(function (node) {
            return node.model.name === "domain.com";
            });

        function idEq(name) {
            return function (node) {
             return node.model.name === name;
            };
         }

        var rootDomainHttp = "http://www.domain.com";
        var rootDomainHttps = "https://www.domain.com";
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

                loc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("loc");
                for(i=0;i<loc.length;i++) {

                    var fullURL = loc[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    //console.log(fullURL);
                    if(fullURL == rootDomainHttp || fullURL == rootDomainHttps)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createTextNode( loc[i].firstChild.nodeValue ));
                        document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fullURL = fullURL.replace(rootDomainHttps, '');
                        fullURL = fullURL.replace(rootDomainHttp, '');

                        var urlComponents = fullURL.split ('/').filter(function(el) {return el.length != 0});;
                        //console.log(urlComponents);
                        var arrayLength = urlComponents.length;
                        var currentNode;
                        var parentNode = root.first(idEq("domain.com"));
                        //console.log(fullURL);
                        for (var component in urlComponents) {
                            if (urlComponents.hasOwnProperty(component)) { 

                                //console.log("started loop for URL components: " + urlComponents[component]);

                                var currentNode = root.first(idEq(urlComponents[component]));

                                if (currentNode == undefined)
                                {

                                    parentNode.addChild(tree.parse({name: urlComponents[component]}));

                                    parentNode = root.first(idEq(urlComponents[component]));

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    var currentNode = root.first(idEq(urlComponents[component]));


                                    var componentLevel = component;

                                    var nodesThatMatchPredicate = root.all(function (node) {
                                        return node.model.name == urlComponents[component];
                                    });
                                    var nodeLevel = 0;
                                    for(var node in nodesThatMatchPredicate)
                                    {
                                        if(nodeLevel != component)
                                        {

                                            parentNode.addChild(tree.parse({name: urlComponents[component]}));
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            //console.log("already exists...");
                                        }
                                    }   
                                    var parentNode = root.first(idEq(urlComponents[component]));
                                }
                             }
                        }                   
                        document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createTextNode( loc[i].firstChild.nodeValue ));
                        document.getElementById("urls").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "sitemap_001.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(root));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(root.model));

        //console.log(root);

        /*var url = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent("something");
                        window.open(url, '_blank');
                        window.focus();*/

        })();

    </script>

I am using a <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jnuno.com/tree-model-js/vendor/jnuno/TreeModel.js"></script> library.
```

On the console, when I do console.log(root); I get:
 Node {config: Object, model: Object, children: Array[0], isRoot: function, hasChildren: function…}children: Array[2]config: Objectmodel: Objectchildren: Array[2]0: Objectchildren: Array[1]name: "healthcarezone"proto: Object1: Objectchildren: Array[1]name: "protection"proto: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]name: "domain.com"proto: Object__proto__: Node

But when accessing it directly. It gives me undefined. Any help and examples much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Occasionally javascript does not execute in the order that you would expect.  [This article](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-13/execution-of-javascript-programs) may help you.

I think that a line of code is taking too long to return the value of a variable that a latter line is dependent on.  As a result you can get null and undefined values when running calculations off of variables that are non existent.  You probably should be using callback functions to ensure that your variables are returned before you try to use said variables.